# What is the object that stores "files"

Tags: apex, custom-field, sobject, schema

Which object stores the files (not attachments)?  I'm looking to access this via a trigger.

Is it possible to add a field to this document/file objects?

Answer (score 12):

- The actual "content" of the file is saved as a `ContentVersion`
- `ContentVersion` can have custom fields
- `ContentVersion` is a child of `ContentDocument` - an object implicitly created by SFDC when the first `ContentVersion` is created for that file. Subsequent file versions are save as the 2nd, 3rd, ... children of `ContentDocument`  You can think of `ContentDocument` as a 'header' for all of the versions of that document.
- `ContentDocument` (and thus, the latest `ContentVersion`) is connected to the target object from whence the original file was uploaded via `ContentDocumentLink` (e.g. a link between `Opportunity` and `ContentDocument`)

Comment: Where is the body blob of the file stored? This way I can upload it to an external site?

Comment: @tjcinnamon - see `ContentVersion.VersionData`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much!  I may need to figure out how to turn this into a binary stream but that's a different question :)

Answer (score 6):

`ContentDocument` is the object and `ContentDocumentLink` is the object that connects that file to a given record.

You cannot add custom fields to either of those two objects.

Comment: dang!  I was hoping to add a long text area to help index these documents.  Is there a different object that indexes these?

Comment: A better question would have been, "where does is the data of indexed documents stored"?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe it would be under ContentVersion

Comment: I'm looking that ContentDocument in the workbench and doing a SOQL query on the id and it says there's none