# Can dataloader.io export files (not attachments)?

Tags: dataloader.io

As far as I can see in the documentation, dataloader.io only supports exporting Attachments rather than Files.

https://dataloader.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/218984278

Based on this ([What is the object that stores "files"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153106/what-is-the-object-that-stores-files)) it seems like ContentVersion.VersionData is the equivalent to Attachment.Body for downloading Files.

It looks to me like since ContentVersion is in the list for Dataloader.io. I can't test this myself as the user that I am accessing for this has limited access, so can't simply create a file.

Can anyone confirm that they have successfully exported Files from a Salesforce Org using the ContentVersion object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi @frackham, you can export the files using contentversion object but
>   only problem is versiondata you will get is in blob datatype. But in
>   attachment you are getting it as zip file. That's the difference. That
>   you may be not wanting.

[image]

Comment: No problem with blob (not my preference, but I can work with that).

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say 'export the files' you mean Files, and not export the Attachments? My use case is that I want to export *Files*, not Attachments via a different route :)

Comment: Files in Salesforce refers content Object. ContentVersion will give you the files only, Not the attachment. But in your query, do remember to use islatest=true. If not, you can have multiple version of the same file.

Comment: If you are not concerned about the version data, better to go with the ContentDocument object. ContentVersion is related to ContentDocument.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Comment: @frackham  Welcome :)